# sinatra helper in external file

Tags: sinatra

I have lot of helpers in my main Sinatra project_name.rb and I want to remove them to the external file, what is the best practice to do that ?

from **./preject_name.rb**

```
   helpers do
     ...#bunch of helpers
   end
```

to for exapmple **./helpers/something.rb**

thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as you said it yourself:

Move the `helpers` block into another file and `require` it where you need.

```
#helpers.rb
helpers do
...
end

#project_name.rb
require 'path/to/helpers.rb'
```

Comment: lol, simple :) why didn't I tryied in firstplace :) thank you, I used is like `require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/helpers/helpers.rb"`

Comment: When you use Ruby 1.9.2 you might aswell use `require_relative 'helpers/helpers'` instead of that `File`-construct

Comment: what's the advantage ? ... and I kinda want this project to run on all machines, will be on github for share :)

Comment: Not sure if it has any impact besides it just looks better/cleaner imho.

Comment: See my answer. I think we should use modules especially when we are working on modular Sinatra applications.

Answer (score 30):

The simple and recommended way:

```
module ApplicationHelper

# methods

end

class Main < Sinatra::Base

  helpers ApplicationHelper

end
```

Answer (score 15):

Alas, if, like me, you are building a *modular* Sinatra app, it's a little more complex than simply moving the `helpers` out into another file.

The only way I got this to work is as follows.

first up in your app (I'll call this `my_modular_app.rb`)

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/some_helpers'

class MyModularApp < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::SomeHelpers

  ...

end
```

and then create the folder structure `./lib/sinatra/` and create `some_helpers.rb` as follows:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module SomeHelpers

    def help_me_world
      logger.debug "hello from a helper"
    end

  end

  helpers SomeHelpers

end
```

doing this you can simply split all your helpers up into multiple files, affording more clarity in larger projects.

Comment: I think it can be more simple. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the answer @DaveSag offered miss something. Should add a line at the beginning of `my_modular_app.rb`:

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)  # add ./lib to $LOAD_PATH

require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/some_helpers' # this line breaks unless line 1 is added.

# more code below...
```

In addition, if someone prefers a "classical style" like me, the following is for you :)

In **app.rb**

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)

require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/some_helpers'

get '/' do
  hello_world
end
```

In **lib/sinatra/some_helpers.rb**

```
module Sinatra
  module SomeHelper
    def hello_world
      "Hello World from Helper!!"
    end
  end

  helpers SomeHelper
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `require_relative './lib/sinatra/helpers'` to my `config.ru` and that's all.

So it looks like this:

```
require_relative './config/environment'
require_relative './lib/sinatra/helpers'
use ProjectsController
run ApplicationController
```

and my `./lib/sinatra/helpers.rb` file is not even a module and I don't use any requires or includes in it. I can just define methods straight in this file and use them all over the app.

The answer of @kgpdeveloper didn't work for me.