# Sinatra Helper in External File gives LoadError

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to add a helper to connect to a mongo db to my modular Sinatra application

When I type `foreman start` in my console I get:

```
/home/sunny/Programs/landing_pages/app.rb:17:in `block in <class:LandingPages>': undefined local variable or method `connect' for LandingPages:Class (NameError)
```

My `app.rb` file looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra/base' 
require 'sinatra/partial'
require 'sinatra/db_helper'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'mongo'

class LandingPages < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::DbHelper

  configure do
    $collection = connect
  end 
end
```

My `./lib/sinatra/db_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module DbHelper
    def connect
      conn = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost")
      db = conn.db("leads")
      db.collection("laws")
    end 
  end 

  helpers DbHelper
end
```

My `config.ru` looks like this:

```
require './app'

run LandingPages
```

I thought I was following the instructions correctly on:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html

but I'm not totally sure. I'm not making a gem but just a sinatra app so maybe my directory hierarchy isn't correct. I don't have a rake file or a gem spec. Do I need them?

Some googling also found this:

[sinatra helper in external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916626/sinatra-helper-in-external-file)

Dave Sag answers my question perfectly but I can't get it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes about because of the scope of methods created through the `helpers` is on the sinatra application instance, since it calls ruby's `include` under the hood.  So this would work:

```
get '/some/route' do
  db = connect
  # do something else ...
end
```

But the configure block has a class scope, so it can be used for configuring the application as a whole.  So to make this work, you can define the method as:

```
module Sinatra
  module DbHelper
    def self.connect
      conn = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost")
      db = conn.db("leads")
      db.collection("laws")
    end 
  end 
end
```

which could then be called via:  `$collection = Sinatra::DbHelper.connect` or perhaps more favoured, you could call `register` instead of `helpers`.  `register` calls `extend` under the hood, so you end up with class level methods (if you extend a class, anyway).  You could then make the configure block as so:

```
configure do |app|
  $collection = app.connect
end
```

You could also do all of this in an `registered` method on the DbHelpers module.  See the example in the documentation for how this might work.